# Resizing P5 Canvas according to image size

Tags: javascript, dom, canvas, drag-and-drop, processing

Please take a look at the following P5 code.

The point of this small app is to drag and drop an image on the canvas changing its size according to the "uploaded" image's width and height.

```
/**************************************************/
//GENERAL
var canvas;
//IMAGE
var img;//image
var imgW;//image width
var imgH;//image height
/**************************************************/
function setup(){
  canvas = createCanvas(710, 400);//initial canvas size
  canvas.drop(gotFile);
}
/**************************************************/
function draw(){
    background(0);
    if(img){
    image(img, 0, 0);
    imgW = img.width;
    imgH = img.height;
        if(imgW > 0 && imgH > 0){
            resizeCanvas(imgW, imgH);
        }
    }
    fill(255);
    text(imgW + ", " + imgH, 10, 10);
}
/**************************************************/
//
function gotFile(file){
  if (file.type === 'image') {
    img = createImg(file.data).hide();
  }
}
/**************************************************/
function mouseClicked(){
    if(img){
        if(imgW > 0 && imgH > 0){
            resizeCanvas(imgW, imgH);
        }
    }
}
```

Using `draw()`:
Once the image has been loaded successfully (at least displaying it), I assign its width and height to the variables `imgW` and `imgH`. Followed by the canvas size change... which leads to an error, the canvas' size the same as the uploaded image (checked on `Developer Tools`) but doesn't display anything.

Using `mouseClicked()`:
When disabling the canvas size change on `draw()`, and click on the canvas, the resize happens perfectly showing the image.

The application needs to work without clicking, it should be automatic change (canvas size) after dropping the image.

**UPDATE**

This is what I see on the console when dropping the 
The error I get on the console:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at p5.Color._parseInputs (p5.js:44096)
    at new p5.Color (p5.js:43147)
    at p5.color (p5.js:42827)
    at p5.Renderer2D.background (p5.js:50315)
    at p5.background (p5.js:44288)
    at draw (sketch.js:21)
    at p5.redraw (p5.js:52435)
    at p5.resizeCanvas (p5.js:51826)
    at draw (sketch.js:30)
```

**UPDATE 2**

This is how the code looks like now, calling the resizeCanvas on the drop method:

```
/**************************************************/
//GENERAL
var canvas;
//IMAGE
var img;
var imgW;
var imgH;
var z;
/**************************************************/
function setup(){
  canvas = createCanvas(710, 400);
  canvas.drop(gotFile); 
}
/**************************************************/
function draw(){
    background(0);
    //
    if(img){
        imgUpdate();
    }
    //debug
    fill(255);
    text(imgW + ", " + imgH, 10, 10);
}
/**************************************************/
function gotFile(file){
  if (file.type === 'image') {
    img = createImg(file.data).hide();
  }
  while (!img) {

  }
  createP("Uploaded");

  if(img)
  {
    imgUpdate();
    resizeCanvas(imgW, imgH);
  }
}
/**************************************************/
function mouseClicked(){
    if(img)
    {
        if(imgW > 0 && imgH > 0)
        {
            resizeCanvas(imgW, imgH);
        }
    }
}
/**************************************************/
function imgUpdate()
{
    image(img, 0, 0);
    imgW = img.width;
    imgH = img.height;
}
/**************************************************/
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The canvas doesn't display the image anymore. It doesn't display anything.
Please watch short video capture (first test shows the error): https://www.screencast.com/t/vS7GZuAGPa

Comment: Do you see any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: Please see UPDATE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the asynchronous loading of the image data. You can use the [loadImage()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadImage) method, take advantage of the success callback and write *gotFile* like this:

```
function gotFile(file){
  if (file.type === 'image') {
    img = loadImage(file.data, 
                    function(){
                      imgUpdate();
                      resizeCanvas(imgW, imgH);
                    });
  }

  createP("Uploaded");
}
```

Comment: Works perfect!.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the `draw()` function is called 60 times per second. It's also called whenever you call the `resizeCanvas()` function.

You call `resizeCanvas()` which calls `draw()` which calls `resizeCanvas()` which calls `draw()` until you eventually get your error.

To fix this, you need to stop calling `resizeCanvas()` every frame. It looks like you can probably call it from inside the `gotFile()` function instead?

**Edit:** After fixing that problem, your next problem is caused by the fact that JavaScript loads images asynchronously. Think about what happens on this line:

```
img = createImg(file.data).hide();
```

The `createImg()` file takes a URL, and begins loading the image in the background while your code continues to execute. Then you use `img` to resize the canvas, but the image isn't actually done loading yet, so the width and height are undefined. Try printing some values to the console to see what I mean.

To fix this problem, you need to wait until the image is actually loaded. I think you're trying to do that with your `while` loop, but note that your loop isn't doing much because `img` will always be defined the first time through. You need to go one level deeper and check the width and height of the image before you use it.

You could also use the [p5.File](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.File) reference to check the file type before continuing and do something like show a progress bar while the image loads.

Comment: Please see **Update 2**

Comment: It adds the gragged picture file ONLY when you make a click.